# Relationships using Realm.io with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have leagues that have teams that have players.  A player can belong to different teams and leagues.  A team can belong to different leagues.  I am having trouble setting these relationships with Realm.

```
class League: RLMObject
{
    dynamic var name = "name"

    dynamic var teams = RLMArray(objectClassName: Team.className())
}


class Team: RLMObject
{
    dynamic var name = "name"

    var leagues: [League] {
        return linkingObjectsOfClass("League", forProperty: "teams") as [League]
    }

    dynamic var players = RLMArray(objectClassName: Player.className())
}


class Player: RLMObject
{
    dynamic var name = "name"

    var teams: [Team] {
        return linkingObjectsOfClass("Team", forProperty: "players") as [Team]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The relationships are correct, it was the way I was presenting the data on the view that was the problem.  So this is an example of the correct way of representing these relationships.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get things working! Let us know if you have any new questions!